# Customizing CSS classes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

I am working on an application where the user will be allowed to change the font color of header titles.

The header titles use a value from cssClass (the cssClass uses font-size, font-color, font-weight & font-family).

Is there a way that I can allow a custom font-color in the css file itself?

One option would be to eliminate font-color from the cssClass, and use Font-Color in the .aspx page.

Comment: How do you intend on having the user pick the color? Did you want a postback? Did you want to use JavaScript to achive this?

Comment: javascript would be better...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem in having `color` inside your CSS file and also inline on any HTML element, since inline styles will override the color defined on the file.

Imagine your CSS have this:

```
a#lnkTest { color: #ff0000; }
```

But you do it on your *aspx.vb*:

```
lnkTest.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Your generated HTML will be:

```
 <a id="lnkTest" style="color: #0000ff">Bla bla bla</a>
```

So, the overrided color works without problems. Also, if you want to do it with JavaScript, it works in the same way:

```
document.getElementById("lnkTest").style.color = "#0000ff";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are letting user's pick just their own font color, it's probably easiest to set the `Font-Color` attribute or set an inline `style` attribute on the client side. If you did it on the client side, the interface would be snappier (not requiring a postback for a color change), but you would need to save the user's choice somewhere and set it again on postback.

Here's an example of setting the header colors on the client-side:

**With jQuery**

```
function setHeaderColor(color) {
    // The color parameters should be of the form '#000000'
    $('h1, h2, h3').css({ color: color });
}
```

**Without jQuery**

```
function setHeaderColor(color) {
    var hdrs = [].concat(document.getElementsByTagName('h1'))
                 .concat(document.getElementsByTagName('h2'))
                 .concat(document.getElementsByTagName('h3')),
        ii, jj;

    for (ii = 0; ii < hdrs.length; ii += 1) {
        for (jj = 0; jj < hdrs[ii].length; jj += 1) {
            hdrs[ii].item(jj).style.color = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your sample, 'h1' is the ID value of the control, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use a label control between the <h1> tags and use System.Drawing.Color to apply the color.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamically created css file, i.e. an aspx page that only output css.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

h1 {
font-size: 15px;
color: <%= myUsersColor () %>;
}
```

Comment: How would I call the "h1" styling to my label?

Comment: Well your question told about "heading titles", so I assumed h1. You can put wathever selector you want. It was just an exemple of generated css file.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to dynamic change the style of the element.